# The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out double)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, vb.net

I did a search and didn't find an answer to my question.  If it's already been asked, I'd appreciate some help finding it.

I'm a bit new to coding and I'm trying to convert a program from VB to C#.

Here is the original VB code:

```
For Each grpkey In groups.Keys.ToArray
  Dim grp = groups(grpkey)
  If grp.SmartKitParameters.Count > 0 Then
    Dim partnameparam = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%SMARTKITNAME%", "")
    Dim maintcodeparam = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%MAINTCODE%", "P")
    Dim divisioncodeparam = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%DIVISIONCODE%", "W")
    Dim quantityparam As Double
    Double.TryParse(GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%QUANTITY%", "0"), quantityparam)
    Dim smkt As New Part With
    {
      .PartID = allparts.Values.Max(Function(p) p.PartID) + 1,
      .DPLType = grp.Parts.Values.First.DPLType,
      .Plane = grp.Parts.Values.First.Plane,
      .Quantity = quantityparam,
      .MaintCode = maintcodeparam,
      .PartNumber = partnameparam,
      .Plant = divisioncodeparam,
    }
    Dim parentgrp = GetGroup(groups, smkt.DPLType, smkt.Plane, "(Default Group)")
    parentgrp.Parts.Add(smkt.PartID, smkt)

    allparts.Add(smkt.PartID, smkt)

    groups.Remove(grpkey)
  End If

  Using specdimscmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From DPLSpecialDimensions;", conn)
    Using rdr = specdimscmd.ExecuteReader
      While rdr.Read
        Dim partid = rdr.GetInteger("PartID", 0)
        If allparts.ContainsKey(partid) Then
              allparts(partid).SpecialDimensions.Add(New SpecialDimension With
              {
                .PartID = partid,
                .SpecDimID = rdr.GetInteger("SpecDimID", 0),
                .MaintCode = rdr.GetString("MaintCode", ""),
                .SpecialType = rdr.GetString("SpecialType", ""),
                .SpecialDim = rdr.GetSingle("SpecialDim", 0.0)
              })
        End If
      End While
    End Using
  End Using
Next
```

Here is what I've done to convert this to C# code:

```
1  foreach (string grpkey_loopVariable in groups.Keys.ToArray)
2  {
3    if (grp.SmartKitParameters.Count > 0)
4    {
5      string partnameparam = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%SMARTKITNAME%", "");
6      string maintcodeparam = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%MAINTCODE%", "P");
7      string divisioncodeparam = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%DIVISIONCODE%", "W");
8      double quantityparam = 0;
9      string quantityparamstring = GetParameterValue(grp.SmartKitParameters, "%QUANTITY%", "0.0");
10     double.TryParse(quantityparamstring, quantityparam);
11
12     Part smkt = new Part
13     {
14       PartID = allparts.Values.Max(p => p.PartID) + 1,
15       DPLType = grp.Parts.Values.First().DPLType,
16       Plane = grp.Parts.Values.First().Plane,
17       Quantity = quantityparam,
18       MaintCode = maintcodeparam,
19       PartNumber = partnameparam,
20       Plant = divisioncodeparam,
21     };
22
23   dynamic parentgrp = GetGroup(groups, smkt.DPLType, smkt.Plane, "(Default Group)");
24   parentgrp.Parts.Add(smkt.PartID, smkt);
25  
26   allparts.Add(smkt.PartID, smkt);
27
28   groups.Remove(grpkey);
29 }
30
31 using (OleDbCommand specdimscmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From DPLSpecialDimensions;", conn))
32 {
33   using (OleDbDataReader rdr = specdimscmd.ExecuteReader())
34   {
35     while (rdr.Read())
36     {
37       dynamic partid = GetInteger(rdr as IDataReader, "PartID", 0);
38       if (allparts.ContainsKey(partid))
39       {
40         allparts[partid].SpecialDimensions.Add(new SpecialDimension
41         {
42           PartID = partid,
43           SpecDimID = GetInteger(rdr as IDataReader, "SpecDimID", 0),
44           MaintCode = GetString(rdr as IDataReader, "MaintCode", ""),
45           SpecialType = GetString(rdr as IDataReader, "SpecialType", ""),
46           SpecialDim = GetSingle(rdr as IDataReader, "SpecialDim", 0)
47          });
48        }
49      }
50    }
51  }
52}
```

at line 10 in the C# code, I am getting the error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out double)' has some invalid arguments

This doesn't make sense to me since the arguments are the correct type (string and double).  Are they invalid arguments in some other way?

Comment: You need the `out` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doubleParam` is an `out` parameter, so you should explictly tell it so:

```
double.TryParse(quantityparamstring, out quantityparam);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Note that `double.TryParse` returns a bool, true if successful (and the out parameter is useful), false if not.  I don't know if your code guarantees that to be a properly formatted double, but if it isn't, you may want to modify it to use this return value.

Answer (score 1):

Change that line to below using the `out` keyword

```
double.TryParse(quantityparamstring, out quantityparam);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: @AmmonNelson, alright but you should refer documentation anytime such confusion occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "refer documentation," please clarify.

Comment: @AmmonNelson, I mean https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I will.